# Uint8Array to Short int conversion in JavaScript results in negative number

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer, short, arraybuffer

I'm trying to get exif data from JPG using JavaScript in the browser.
I'm using FileReader() class and readAsArrayBuffer() method.
For most operations I need Uint8Array, so that's what I'm casting ArrayBuffer to.
I've added function to objects of Uint8Array for when I need short:

```
const getShort = function(position, bigEndian = true) {
  const int1 = this[position];
  const int2 = this[position+1];
  let result = (int1 << 8) | (int2 & 0xFF);
  if(!bigEndian) {
    let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
    let view = new DataView(buffer);
    view.setInt16(1,result);

    result = view.getInt16(1, true) ;
  }
  return(result);
}
```

The problem is when parsing `0110 1001` and `1000 0111` I'm getting `1000 0111 0110 1001` and that is interpreted as `-30871` instead of `34665`.

Comment: Can you ad an input example for this function?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/hinolobedo/edit?js,console